# Is It Possible To Use Push Notification Windows 8 Metro App's With Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8, push-notification, windows-runtime

We have a Windows 8 application which was developed with JavaScript and HTML.

Now, i want to add push notification functionality to our application. But after i some research i realized that only C#, VB.Net, C++ and XAML applications support this feature.

Also because of some reasons we can't use Azure; so i have to develop server-side and host our Windows Servers.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the client side please check MSDN documentation here:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Push-and-periodic-de225603

As for the server side, Pushwoosh.com is planning to support win8 push notifications till the end of September.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript apps on Windows 8 are not incompatible with Push Notifications - you have access to all Windows Runtime functionality from Javascript/HTML5 apps.

For example, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh465412 "How to request, create, and save a notification channel (Windows Store apps using JavaScript and HTML)" for how to obtain a push channel notification channel in your JS app.

Comment: yes you are right, but the main objective of the question is Azure. Is it possible without Azure?

Comment: Yes, it's possible without Azure - the WNS protocol is a simple HTTPS-based protocol which you can use to send pushes from anywhere. Your server side infrastructure can run on whatever platform/host you're most comfortable with.